# How does the classloader choose between multiple classes with the same package and name

Tags: java, android, classloader

I am writing an Android project that needs to use the Apache HttpClient from version 4.1 of the project. I am including this in the libs folder of the project as a jar file. My question is how does the class loader know to use the version 4 class instead of the platform supplied version 3, as they both have the same package name and the same import statement?

I encountered a problem when using a GSON library in the past which clashed with the one included by HTC [see here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=255) and wonder how these situations differ (maybe because gson is using reflection?)? Any info would be great thanks.

Comment: Your situation doesn't differ. You should also rename the packages if you want to make sure that your classes are loaded, and not the classes provided by the OS.

Comment: Does changing the HttpClient packages using jarjar help you here? http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classloader looks in his classes first and after that the parent classloader is asked.
Thr problem may be that the parent classloader has a patched class that works in android, while the version you are providing is not. This may lead to problems.

Long story short:
Classloader are stored in a tree and when the class is not found the parent classloader is asked.
(custom classloaders may do something different!)

Comment: +1 This makes sense. How come the bug referred to above happens in that case? I wouldve thought the GSON lob included in the system would be associated with a parent classloader?

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient 4 and HttpClient 3 are two totally different libraries. HttpClient 4 is a total rewrite and was designed to follow many [RFC's available](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

HttpClient 4 is **not** backward compatible to HttpClient 3.

Comment: sure, but HttpClient has the same package name for boths libs does it not?

Comment: No entirely, some classes may have the same package name but entirely different method signature/constructor.

Comment: yes but the class is loaded based on the import statement withourtregard to the interface though, is it not?

Comment: @Dori, the class loader will interrogates its parent classloaders for classes with **specific** constructor/method signature. Whoever has it, returns the object else it finds it itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Android but if it's similar to how JBoss it does, for example, then you have custom class loaders that first look in the app classpath and if nothing is found there they'd check the system classpath. As I said, I'm not sure the same is true for Android, though.